# Shortening the sentence to find a search value

Tags: sql, sql-like

Searching for values that uses the same value

Example

```
SELECT Name, UnitPrice, Quantity, Color
FROM Product
WHERE Name Like '2' OR UnitPrice Like '2' OR Quantity LIKE '2' OR  Color LIKE '2'
```

is there a way to shorten the sentence so that i do not need to repeat Variable LIKE 'value'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LIKE` without wildcards is `=`

```
SELECT Name, UnitPrice, Quantity, Color
FROM Product
WHERE '2' IN (Name, UnitPrice, Quantity, Color)
```

This expands out to a series of OR conditions
Note that the string `'2'` will be CAST as needed after OR expansion

If you *do* require wild cards and LIKE, you'd have to use a series of OR statements.

Finally, this won't scale performance-wise. With good indexing, (eg one per column and other 2 as INCLUDE columns) then this would probably be better written as separate queries with UNION between them

Edit, for clarity

OP wants to use wildcards. Therefore my `IN` suggestion will not work. So you **have** to do this

```
WHERE
    Name Like '%2%' OR
    UnitPrice Like '%2%' OR 
    Quantity LIKE '%2%' OR
    Color LIKE '%2%'
```

Because of the leading wildcard, there is no point adding indexes. So my text above about indexes+includes is irrelevant

Comment: Thanks it does work but i realise that i forgot to add in if the value if '28' then this sql would not work. Cause it does not accept %

Comment: @unknown: your example does not have wildcards and will not find '28'. Also, when looking for a quantity of 2, why would you want 28? Searching in a name (.. LIKE '%2%') I can understand. Please make your questions more clear: and note that I covered the possibility of you really want wildcards...

Comment: Yeah. I did read about performance wise if there is too many 'or'. I only do not understand one per column and other 2 as include columns. Did you mean where '2' IN (Name, UnitPrice, Quantity, Color). I would like an example like '%2%' so that it will find anything that is related to 2. If it is possible.

Comment: @unknown: updated my answer. You have to decide if you want wildcards or not: it affects the SQL and your index choices.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I will think about it again on your suggestion. ;)